# VMWare Workstation Host-Only causes Slow Host Internet

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have need to put two of my VM's on the same network, a network that doesn't have or share internet.  So I set up a "host-only" network.  The trouble is, when I launch either of the two VM's, the internet on the host machine becomes difficult to use, it slows or doesn't work.  The host-only network is on a different subnet and subnet mask.  Is this a necessary side effect of using host-only networking?  Is there a better way to do this?

> Host PC

Internet Adapter 192.168.9.xxx
255.255.255.0

Host-only adapter 192.168.10.1 255.255.254.0

> Host-only network

vm1
192.168.11.1
255.255.254.0

vm2
192.168.11.0
255.255.254.0

Comment: Is your subnetting correct? Why the mask is 23 bits and how have you planned the subnets? Something seems off to me.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen what do you recommend I set it to?

Comment: Jeez, I haven't been doing those in a long time. Can you do like mask of 25 for example (255.255.255.128), and network addresses of 192.168.10.0 and 192.168.10.128? Is that "more" correct? I have a doubt that this won't fix your problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, there is no conflict between the Internet and Host-only networks. The host machine runs slowly or does not run. It may be because opening any virtual machine causes insufficient system memory. It is recommended to check system performance, CPU,memory and hard disk usage when running the virtual machine.

Comment: I wish I could agree with you, but this just isn't the case.  The system has 64GB of RAM.  And this system typically runs virtual machines as it's normal form of function.  Even now with 2x Visual Studio, 2x VM's,  Chrome, SSMS, MSSQL Server, Teamviewer, and Outlook open,  30% CPU, 44% Memory.  Again, none of these issues occur until the Host-Only adapter is enabled in a VM.